# How to manipulate a CSV object in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I want to export some ActiveRecords in CSV format. After check some tutorials, I found this:

```
def export_as_csv(equipments)
  attributes = %w[id title description category_id]
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
  csv << attributes
    equipments.each do |equipment|
      csv << equipment.attributes.values_at(*attributes)
    end
    return csv
  end
end
```

The problem is, I want to manipulate all in memory in my tests(i.e. I don't want to save the file in the disk). So, when I receive this csv object as return value, how I can iterate through rows and columns? I came  from Python and so I tried:

```
csv = exporter.export_as_csv(equipments)
for row in csv:
  foo(row)
```

But obviously didn't work. Also, the equipments are surely not nil.

Comment: If you need to access separate rows and columns, then you don't need CSV yet. Return array of arrays. Otherwise it seems a waste of resources to generate CSV only to parse it right away.

Comment: Actually, we want to be able to export our data of our project in JSON and also in CSV. The reason that I don't want to save in the disk is because of the test itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some videos, I found that the `return` was the problem. Returning the CSV I was receiving a CSV object, and not the CSV itself.

Answer (score 0):

`CSV.generate` returns string formatted according csv rules.
 So the most obvious way is to parse it and iterate, like:

```
csv = exporter.expor_as_csv(equipments)
CSV.parse(csv).each do |line|
  # line => ['a', 'b', 'c']
end
```

Comment: When I tried to run your suggestion, Ruby started to say:
`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)`